# Create a Martingale out of a Markov Chain.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, markov-chains

Consider a homogeneous finite state  Markov chain $\{X_n\}$ with transition matrix $P$ and state set $S$ consisting of real numbers. 
How to choose the elements of $S$ so that $\{X_n\}$ be a martingale? 
My conjecture is that the set of stationary state probabilities (if they exist) can be used as a suitable $S$ iff $P$ is doubly stochastic. Can you prove or falsify this statement?

Comment: What does it mean to choose S if S is the (given) state space of a given Markov chain X?

Comment: $S$ is a finite set of reals. Choose the suitable reals: this is what I meant.

Comment: I've changed the original accordingly.

Comment: This sems to ask, rather confusingly, how to solve $P\xi=\xi$ and/or how to relate the solutions $\xi$ to the stationary measure $\pi$, which by definition solves $\pi P=\pi$. The rest should follow.

Comment: Yes, indeed. Thank you.